# CodeIgniter Log Out Could still access the page after logging out when back button is clicked or typed a shortcut link

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, session, logout

Hi Everyone i asking if how i can resolved this kind of problem. the problem is when i clicked the back button after logging out the user can still access the page or by typing the link of the page. i thought if i can destroy the session it will automatically disabled those pages..

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Auth extends MY_Controller {

   public function index(){

    $this->data['page_title'] = "User Login";
    $this->load->view('templates/master', $this->data);

     }
public function login(){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $data = $this->User_model->login ($username, $password);
    if($data){  
    $this->session->set_userdata('users', $data);
    $session_data = array(
        'username' => $username);
    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    redirect('users');

    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata
        ('loginfail','<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Danger !</strong> Invalid Email or Password .</div>');
       return redirect("auth");


    } 
}
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username','id'));
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('auth');

}
```

}

```
<a href="<?php echo ('auth/logout')?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
    Logout
  </a>
```

> My Homepage controller Code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        if(empty($this->session->userdata('id'))){
            redirect('auth/logout');
        }
     }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['page_title'] = "Users List";

        $this->data['users'] = $this->User_model->get();
        $this->load->view('templates/master', $this->data);
    }

    public function add()
    {   
        $this->data['page_title'] = "Add User";

        $input_data = $this->input->post(); 

        if(!empty($input_data))
        {
            $this->User_model->insert($input_data);
            redirect('/users');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('templates/master', $this->data);
        }

    }



    public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->data['page_title'] = "Edit User";

        $input_data = $this->input->post(); 

        if(!empty($input_data)){
            $this->User_model->update($input_data);
            redirect('/users');
        } else {
            $this->data['users'] = $this->User_model->get($id);
            $this->load->view('templates/master', $this->data);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->User_model->delete($id);
        redirect('/users');
    }
}
```

> My Core Controller Code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        define('CONTROLLER', $this->router->fetch_class());
        define('METHOD', $this->router->fetch_method());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must log out of the user session. And you have to check the user session in the constructor of a controller.

Example:

```
class Users extends MY_Controller {
   function __construct() {
       if(empty($this->session->userdata())){
          redirect('LOGIN_CONTROLLER');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got completely destroy the session after logout but when i clicked the back button the page will redirect to the page and the session start again

Comment: it will link to my homepage again if i click back after log out.

Comment: I updated my code at the top , that's my homepage controller code

Comment: it seems that you have not added constructor in your User controller. So please  add and  let me know.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\Users\Carl\Documents\agscontek\application\controllers\users.php on line 6
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:

Comment: this is the error , i to delete that closing tag  , but still have this error.

Comment: i forgot to show this code @ Shubham Azad, i have a core controller code. is this a possible error why i cant get this function?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to close the if bracket that's why it showing syntax error. So I have updated my answer please check and use it.

Answer (score 1):

logout and login works fine...

but you have to restrict or privilege your functions

example

```
public function isLoggedIn() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('uId') == TRUE) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

public function index() {

    $status = $this->session->userdata('uStatus');
    if ($this->isLoggedIn() == TRUE && $status == "1") {

       //your code here

    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You have to login first');
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect

```
    if(empty($this->session->userdata('id'))){
     redirect('LOGIN_CONTROLLER/METHOD_NAME_HERE');
   }
```

Comment: the error not showing but the page says that the page is not redirecting properly